# jQuery post method to call Coldfusion component function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to call a cfc method via ajax by using jQuery's post() method, but I keep getting an error message saying "the xxx parameter to the yyy function is required but was not passed in". Here's my cfc function:

```
<cffunction name="updateAssessment" returntype="struct" returnformat="json" access="remote" hint="For ajax update of a single assessment record">
    <cfargument name="data" type="JSON" required="true" hint="Data structure received from ajax call">

    <cfset var incomingData = "" />
    <cfset var qry = "" />
    <cfset var resultset = {success:false,message:"invalid data"}>

    <cfif IsJSON(arguments.data)>
        <cfset incomingData = deserializeJSON(arguments.data) />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn resultset />
</cffunction>
```

and here's the jQuery code calling it:

```
$('.ajaxSubmitBtn').on('click', function() {

        //grab values from editable table cells...
        var assessmentid =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ajaxSubmitBtn').val());
        var source =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.sourceTD').text());
        var lname =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.lnameTD').text());
        var fname =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.fnameTD').text());
        var ssn =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ssnTD').text());
        var assessdate = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.assessdateTD').text());
        var casehranum = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.casehranumTD').text());
        var dob = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.dobTD').text());

        //Put values in a JSON object...
        var JSONPacket =  {
            "assessmentid":assessmentid,
            "source":source,
            "lname":lname,
            "fname":fname,
            "ssn":ssn,
            "assessdate":assessdate,
            "casehranum":casehranum,
            "dob":dob
            }

        //call cfc function via ajax using post()
        $.post("../../../cfc/starsImporter.cfc", {method: "updateAssessment", data: JSONPacket},
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        "json");
     });
```

I'm clearly passing the required argument to the cfc function with "data: JSONPacket", so not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the parameters individually. The way it's written now, jQuery is passing the `data` struct as strings with keys like `data[source]`

```
$('.ajaxSubmitBtn').on('click', function() {

    //grab values from editable table cells...
    var assessmentid =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ajaxSubmitBtn').val());
    var source =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.sourceTD').text());
    var lname =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.lnameTD').text());
    var fname =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.fnameTD').text());
    var ssn =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ssnTD').text());
    var assessdate = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.assessdateTD').text());
    var casehranum = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.casehranumTD').text());
    var dob = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.dobTD').text());

    //Put values in a JSON object...
    var JSONPacket =  {
        "method" : "updateAssessment",
        "assessmentid":assessmentid,
        "source":source,
        "lname":lname,
        "fname":fname,
        "ssn":ssn,
        "assessdate":assessdate,
        "casehranum":casehranum,
        "dob":dob
        }

    //call cfc function via ajax using post()
    $.post("../../../cfc/starsImporter.cfc", JSONPacket,
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
    "json");
 });
```

**CFC**

```
<cffunction name="updateAssessment" returntype="struct" returnformat="json" access="remote" hint="For ajax update of a single assessment record">
    <cfargument name="assessmentid" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="source" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="lname" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="fname" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="ssn" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="assessdate" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="casehranum" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="dob" type="string" required="true" />
    ...
```

Comment: This is correct. The original single argument of "data" had an invalid type of "json" in the first place. Check the docs for a list of valid values for type on cfargument. Whichever browser you're using should have developer's tools with a console and a network traffic section. Alternately, there's a free tool called Fiddler that is excellent for this.Your can use that to help diagnose your Ajax calls by checking the request headers to see that the data packet you created sent the data as individual form elements, not as a "struct" or json value.

Answer (score 1):

Got it - the problem was that I needed to stringify the JSONPacket before posting it to the cfc method. And, put a semicolon after creating the JSON object. So everything together looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="updateAssessment" returntype="struct" returnformat="JSON" access="remote" output="false" hint="For ajax update of a single assessment record">
    <cfargument name="JSONPacket" type="string" required="true" hint="Data structure received from ajax call">

    <cfset var incomingData = "" />
    <cfset var qry = "" />
    <cfset var resultset = {success:false,message:"invalid data"}>

    <cfif IsJSON(arguments.JSONPacket)>
        <cfset incomingData = deserializeJSON(arguments.JSONPacket) />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn resultset />
</cffunction>


 $('.ajaxSubmitBtn').on('click', function() {
        //console.log("Hello");
        var assessmentid =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ajaxSubmitBtn').val());
        var source =  $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.sourceTD').text());
        var lname =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.lnameTD').text());
        var fname =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.fnameTD').text());
        var ssn =   $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.ssnTD').text());
        var assessdate = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.assessdateTD').text());
        var casehranum = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.casehranumTD').text());
        var dob = $.trim($(this).closest('tr').find('.dobTD').text());
        var JSONPacket =  {
            "assessmentid":assessmentid,
            "source":source,
            "lname":lname,
            "fname":fname,
            "ssn":ssn,
            "assessdate":assessdate,
            "casehranum":casehranum,
            "dob":dob
            };

        $.post("../../../cfc/starsImporter.cfc", {method:"updateAssessment", JSONPacket:JSON.stringify(JSONPacket)},
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        "JSON");
     });
```